# Syntax in assignment statement l-value

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, iverilog

1. This is code
2. and can't recognize the error
3. it's showing `new_content` as error. I changed its name, but error are also showing

I thing this is a logical error

```
module IF_ID(new_content, instruction, newPC, clk, pwrite1);
input pwrite1, clk;
input [31:0] instruction, newPC;
output [63:0] new_content;
reg [63:0] next;
always (@negedge clk) begin
    if(pwrite1)
        new_content <= {instruction, newPC};
    else
        new_content <= 64'b0;

end

endmodule
```

I get these errors:

```
jdoodle.v:6: syntax error
jdoodle.v:8: Syntax in assignment statement l-value.
jdoodle.v:9: syntax error
jdoodle.v:10: error: invalid module item.
jdoodle.v:12: syntax error
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 types of syntax errors.

You need to declare `new_content` as a `reg` since you make a procedural assignment to it in an `always` block.

You need to place `@` to the left of the `(` in your `always` line.

This code compiles with no errors for me:

```
module IF_ID(new_content, instruction, newPC, clk, pwrite1);
input pwrite1, clk;
input [31:0] instruction, newPC;
output reg [63:0] new_content;
reg [63:0] next;
always @(negedge clk) begin
    if(pwrite1)
        new_content <= {instruction, newPC};
    else
        new_content <= 64'b0;

end
endmodule
```